# How can one enable spectator slots on Left 4 Dead 2 campaign mode?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I have a friend who likes to watch our crew play Left 4 Dead 2, even though she is overwhelmed by the game itself.  Presuming I local host the server, is there a way to set it up so people can join in designated spectator slots?  SourceTV does not appear to work on locally hosted servers.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to rely on a mod to achieve this...

Check out: Left 4 Downtown 2
https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=134032